# I need a 100% certain way to make my GitHub fork & clone equal to the original?

Tags: git, github

I am running into the following problem: I have a GitHub fork with a local clone. My clone (and fork) are 340 commits behind the upstream repository and 2 commits ahead. I want to 'hard' reset my fork & clone *exactly* to the upstream repository, to be specific I want to lose my own commits in the process and recreate the later (this is needed or my pull request will not be accepted by the upstream maintainers).

I can of course delete the fork on GitHub, but I want to do it locally with git commands. Everything I have found so far that would enable me to do this has failed. E.g. I end up with:

```
albus:macports-ports sysbh$ git fetch origin
albus:macports-ports sysbh$ git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at dfb14de3eb5 pypy*-tkinter: ensure UsingTheRightCompiler
albus:macports-ports sysbh$ git push local
To https://github.com/gctwnl/macports-ports.git
 ! [rejected]                master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gctwnl/macports-ports.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

My repositories are locally called 'local' (the fork) and 'origin' (the upstream original). I think it is better for me to make sure that 'original' is called 'upstream' and 'local' is called 'origin', but for now this is the naming.

Answer (score 1):

Just found it

```
git push -f
```

This forces the push. Now on GitHub it is equal.

Comment: You should use the [`--force-with-lease`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-force-with-lease) flag as it will ensure that you _don't overwrite other people's work_. Check out this blog post for more information: https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/

Comment: The fork on the other side is totally mine so I am only overwriting  my own stuff, but thanks.